# Invalid CAST When Returning From Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm running a query and returning a result set from that query. Everything works great except for the customer number data type coming from the AS400 says that it can't CAST no matter what data type I use in my model. I'm sure there is something simple that I'm missing but 12 hours is long enough. I can verify that the customer number field in the as400 is a numeric value however I can't determine exactly what value type it is in the as400.

Here is my list that I'm populating.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Lets add the data to our list we created earlier...
    customerList.Add(new getCustomerInfoModel
    {
        // What returned values do we want to list...
        UMENT = reader.GetString(0),
        UMCUS = reader.GetInt32(1),
        UMNAM = reader.GetString(2),
        UMSLC = reader.GetString(3)
    });
}
```

and my model...

```
public class getCustomerInfoModel
{
    public string UMENT { get; set; }
    public int UMCUS { get; set; }
    public string UMNAM { get; set; }
    public string UMSLC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with GetInt64 instead of GetInt32? You could also try with using the DataTable.Load method. This will fill a DataTable with your data and using a debugger you could easily find what datatype is correct for your column

Comment: The easiest way to figure out what data type it is instead of all this guessing, is to put a breakpoint on that line, then run your program and when it breaks, go to the immediate window and type `?reader.GetFieldType(1)`

Comment: instead of using the GetString or GetInt32 function why don't you use casting along with the actual field name for instance `UMENT = (string)reader['FieldName"]`

Comment: Is it possible the database column allows nulls and you are getting a nullable object back instead of a primitive number type?

Comment: Decimal it was. Thank you for that debugging tip, that's what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The wrong datatype was being used:**

```
UMCUS = reader.GetDecimal(1)
```

This allowed the program to return properly.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Lets add the data to our list we created earlier...
    customerList.Add(new getCustomerInfoModel
    {
        // What returned values do we want to list...
        UMENT = reader.GetString(0),
        UMCUS = reader.GetDecimal(1),
        UMNAM = reader.GetString(2),
        UMSLC = reader.GetString(3)
    });
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class getCustomerInfoModel
{
    public string UMENT { get; set; }
    public Decimal UMCUS { get; set; }
    public string UMNAM { get; set; }
    public string UMSLC { get; set; }
}
```